How do you write an EventGridEvent that can be added via Event Grid Subscriptions in dotnet 8?
I am attempting to learn event grid triggers (which as been going smashing, if smashing is my head between a door and door frame!) and I am working with the following EventGridEvent trigger in an azure function app, running dotnet 8 in isolated mode.
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System.Text.Json;
using CsvHelper;
using System.Globalization;
using Azure.Messaging.EventGrid;

public class BlobTriggerFunction
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly BlobServiceClient _blobServiceClient;

    public BlobTriggerFunction(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<BlobTriggerFunction>();
        _blobServiceClient = blobServiceClient;
    }

    [Function("BlobTriggerFunction")]
    public async Task Run([EventGridTrigger] EventGridEvent eventGridEvent)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Event Grid trigger function processed an event: {eventGridEvent.EventType}");

        if (eventGridEvent.EventType != "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated")
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Ignoring event type: {eventGridEvent.EventType}");
            return;
        }

        var blobCreatedData = eventGridEvent.Data.ToObjectFromJson<BlobCreatedEventData>();
        var sourceContainerName = blobCreatedData.Url.Split('/')[3];
        var sourceBlobName = blobCreatedData.Url.Split('/')[4];

        var destinationContainerName = "secondary";
        var destinationBlobName = Path.ChangeExtension(sourceBlobName, ".csv");

        var sourceBlobClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(sourceContainerName).GetBlobClient(sourceBlobName);
        var destinationBlobClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(destinationContainerName).GetBlobClient(destinationBlobName);

        // Download the source blob content
        using var sourceStream = await sourceBlobClient.OpenReadAsync();
        using var streamReader = new StreamReader(sourceStream);
        var jsonContent = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

        // Parse JSON and convert to CSV
        var jsonArray = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, JsonElement>>>(jsonContent);
        using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
        using var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        if (jsonArray.Any())
        {
            var headers = jsonArray[0].Keys.ToArray();
            foreach (var header in headers)
            {
                csv.WriteField(header);
            }
            csv.NextRecord();

            foreach (var item in jsonArray)
            {
                foreach (var header in headers)
                {
                    if (item.TryGetValue(header, out JsonElement value))
                    {
                        csv.WriteField(value.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        csv.WriteField(string.Empty);
                    }
                }
                csv.NextRecord();
            }
        }

        writer.Flush();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        // Upload the CSV to the destination container
        await destinationBlobClient.UploadAsync(memoryStream, true);

        _logger.LogInformation($"CSV file created and uploaded: {destinationBlobName}");
    }
}

public class BlobCreatedEventData
{
    public string Api { get; set; }
    public string ClientRequestId { get; set; }
    public string RequestId { get; set; }
    public string ETag { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public int ContentLength { get; set; }
    public string BlobType { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Sequencer { get; set; }
    public StorageDiagnostics StorageDiagnostics { get; set; }
}

public class StorageDiagnostics
{
    public string BatchId { get; set; }
}

When running this via func start on my local, I can see BlobTriggerFunction, but when I deploy this to Azure and try to set up a subscription for it within our test topic, I am seeing no available items:

I haven't been able to try much else, as I am very new to this, and a lot of the information in tutorials online seem to be for older versions of both azure portal ui and maybe older versions of the azure function apps (v3, maybe?)
Sorry for the vagueness of this post, as I have basically been told "you know C#, do this!" regardless of if I have worked with event grid before or not.

I have tested that my event grid is working, as a logic app that works on the same event is working perfectly fine, it is just isolated to this app.

Can you explain what you want to do what is this event about and what this function will do?

Firstly created event grid topic as below:

My Program.cs is :
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var rith = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(ri =>
    {
        string rics= "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwik98;AccountKey=k6xRKw1uEsw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
        ri.AddSingleton(new BlobServiceClient(rics));
    })
    .Build();
rith.Run();

Now deployed the Function with your code and deployed to Azure:

Make sure that the function is deployed and the functionality does not have any errors or issues:

Then Opened the Storage account and selected Events, In events Clicked on Create Subscription:

Then Given name and Selected 2 Event Types:

Now Clicked End Point as Azure Function and then Configure an endpoint and given the Function details:

It has been Configured as below:


Thanks Rithwik, but you don't include a sample function in this one, i.e. Function1, so can't test it as a minimal one.

I have used your code only, that is why i did not include

I'll provide an example which is working just fine on my side.
public class Function
{
    private readonly ILogger<Function> _logger;

    public Function(ILogger<Function> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [Function(nameof(Function))]
    public void Run([EventGridTrigger] CloudEvent cloudEvent)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Event type: {type}, Event subject: {subject}", cloudEvent.Type, cloudEvent.Subject);
    }
}

What you should check is if the function app is inside the same region as your event grid topic. Afterwards you should be able to see it in your endpoint configuration like this:

I think that the parameter EventGridEvent is wrong here and it should be CloudEvent instead if you use .NET 8. Please try it with the minimal example and see if it works.

So this small function did appear in my list for a few moments, along with the one I wrote, but both disappeared when I removed your minimal one.
